# Why can't a service startup at boot

Tags: systemd, startup, services

I want to use `systemd` to make a service startup at boot. However I get the message saying that the service is inactive(dead):

```
root@mdchost:/lib/systemd/system# systemctl status mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service
● mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service - MDC Freespace Vldy Fusion Node
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2018-08-04 01:06:48 BST; 5min ago
  Process: 3841 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash /usr/bin/mdc/base/set_limit.sh FUSI mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_
  Process: 3838 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mdc/fusion/mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node (code=exited, status=0/SU
  Process: 3090 ExecStartPre=/opt/x86/ros/kinetic/bin/rosparam load /etc/mdc/fusion/kinematics_dynamic
  Process: 2266 ExecStartPre=/opt/x86/ros/kinetic/bin/rosparam load /etc/mdc/fusion/freespace_vldy_fus
 Main PID: 3838 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

But I can make it startup manually by executing the command:

```
systemctl restart mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service
```

And now the status of the service becomes active(running):

```
root@mdchost:/lib/systemd/system# systemctl status mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service
● mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service - MDC Freespace Vldy Fusion Node
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-08-04 01:29:31 BST; 1s ago
  Process: 2065 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash /usr/bin/mdc/base/set_limit.sh FUSI mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_
  Process: 2017 ExecStartPre=/opt/x86/ros/kinetic/bin/rosparam load /etc/mdc/fusion/kinematics_dynamic
  Process: 1991 ExecStartPre=/opt/x86/ros/kinetic/bin/rosparam load /etc/mdc/fusion/freespace_vldy_fus
 Main PID: 2063 (mdc_freespace_v)
    Tasks: 6
   Memory: 3.5M
      CPU: 469ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service
           └─2063 /usr/bin/mdc/fusion/mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node
```

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Node
Requires=start_roscore.service
After=start_roscore.service

[Service]
User=mdc
Group=mdc

Type=simple
KillMode=proces
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=16
StartLimitInterval=0

EnvironmentFile=/usr/bin/mdc/base/env.cfg
EnvironmentFile=/usr/bin/mdc/ros/ros.cfg

ExecStartPre=/opt/x86/ros/kinetic/bin/rosparam load /etc/mdc/fusion/freespace_vldy_fusion_config.yaml
ExecStartPre=/opt/x86/ros/kinetic/bin/rosparam load /etc/mdc/fusion/kinematics_dynamics.yaml

ExecStart=/usr/bin/mdc/fusion/mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node
ExecReload=/usr/bin/mdc/fusion/mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node

ExecStartPost=/bin/bash /usr/bin/mdc/base/set_limit.sh FUSI mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `journalctl -u  mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service`.

This service exited with 0. There is something about the early boot state the `/usr/bin/mdc/fusion/mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node` didn't like.

Comment: Great, let me see.

Comment: At boot time, `systemd` is probably doing the equivalent of `systemctl start start_roscore.service && systemctl start mdc_freespace_vldy_fusion_node.service`, i.e. starting both services in sequence as fast as possible. If `start_roscore.service` needs a bit more time to set things up after it has nominally started up before it can actually service requests, your service's start-up might be failing because the core is not quite ready yet. The core might need just a few more seconds to become ready, but in computer timescales, much can happen in that time.

Comment: Care to provide more detail as to what you saw in the journal? Did you manage to work around it? Was @telcoM right?